# Ionic camera plugin working in android app but not working in mobile browser?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-camera, ionic3

I am using ionic native camera plugin similar to this [blog](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-using-the-camera-with-ionic-native/). When I build android apk and install it in mobile camera plugin is working as expected. But If I deploy same to firebase hosting and testing by opening it in mobile browser - I am unable to open camera.

How can I make it work in mobile browser?

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** do that with native camera plugin. To use that you must use a device. Because it designed for using device's native camera. In other words, Cordova Plugins use native device code (Swift, JAVA) to perform their functions.

*How can I make it work in a mobile browser?*

If you're developing `PWA (Progressive Web Apps)` then you can use service workers to access the camera on the device. Here you can see [**What Web Can Do Today**](https://whatwebcando.today/).

**Note:** But you cannot use any Cordova plugins with PWA apps.

**Chrome** `Version 60.0.3112.113`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cordova plugins do not work in the browser if you use `ionic-serve` to build your project. Cordova is platform based which means if a plugin developer creates a plugin he needs to add code for every platform he wants to support. In many cases also the `Browser` platform is supported. To make sure you can always check in `plugin.xml` of the plugin you want to use: Search for the following tag: `<platform name="browser">`.

To add the browser platform:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

And then to build/run it for production:

```
ionic cordova run browser --prod
```

You can find the code you need to deploy to your webserver in the `platforms/browser/www` folder.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/browser/CameraProxy.js) you can find the code the camera plugin uses to take a picture when deployed via the browser platform.